# How do I record HDMI input to a file with my Mac

Tags: mac, usb, video, hdmi, quicktime

So I have an HDMI signal and an HDMI to USB adapter. I need to record this HDMI signal to a video file. Zero budget. Will plugging this into my Mac work as a video input? If not, how else do I do this?

Comment: Presumably. Try it.

Comment: Can you share the make and model of your device?

Comment: Macbook Pro 13-inch, Late 2011